# trigger event on a bootstrap switch with VueJS 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I deal with a [boostrap switch](http://bootstrapswitch.com/events.html)

In JQuery, it is easy, you can do as doc state:

```
  $('input[name="my-checkbox"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
    console.log(this); // DOM element
    console.log(event); // jQuery event
    console.log(state); // true | false
});
```

But in VueJS, I can't bind the element to value:

```
<div id="vue-instance">
  <input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" checked @click="log">
</div>

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {

  },
  methods:{
      log(){
          alert('ok');
      }
  },
  mounted(){
    $("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();

  }
});
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xoco70/tfkLkLqw/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use this, you can simply bind to the change on the `mounted` life-cycle hook.

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {

  },
  methods:{
      log(event, state){
          alert('ok');
      }
  },
  mounted(){
    $("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();
    $('input[name="my-checkbox"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', this.log.bind(this));
  }
});
```

I say *If you really need to use this* because you are mixing the data driven approach of `Vue.js` with querying the view with `JQuery`. I also tried coming up with a solution where you could use a `Vue` binding so you could react to events or changes in the model, but it seems the library does not update the value of the html input when the toggle is switched.

Working Example

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    bSwitch: null
  },
  methods:{
      log(event, state){
          this.bSwitch = state;
          console.log('switch to state ' + state );
      }
  },
  mounted(){
   $("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();
    $('input[name="my-checkbox"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', this.log.bind(this));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-switch@3.3.4/dist/js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-switch@3.3.4/dist/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="vue-instance">
  Switch State: {{bSwitch}}
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox">
</div>
```